# Fastlane snapshot warnings "Unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage"

Tags: ios, fastlane

Whilst this does not prevent `fastlane snapshot` from working, I was wondering why I get the following warning (pictured in purple) when running?

[image]

```html
[13:11:17]: ▸ 2018-01-23 13:11:17.281 xcodebuild[87131:11428054]  iPhoneSupport: Unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage on Jack’s Apple Watch (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402653158 "The device is passcode protected." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The device is passcode protected., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
[13:11:17]: ▸ 0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001148bffed DTDKCreateNSError + 113
[13:11:17]: ▸ 1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001148c0831 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 1135
[13:11:17]: ▸ 2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000114901441 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 782
[13:11:17]: ▸ 3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000114901cf8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 488
[13:11:17]: ▸ 4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001147d65ae __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_4 + 216
[13:11:17]: ▸ 5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000108a75a4f __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 806
[13:11:17]: ▸ 6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b10591 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
[13:11:17]: ▸ 7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b08d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
[13:11:17]: ▸ 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b1be76 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
[13:11:17]: ▸ 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b136cb _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
[13:11:17]: ▸ 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b0a941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
[13:11:17]: ▸ 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72b0a6ed _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
[13:11:17]: ▸ 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72dcd1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
[13:11:17]: ▸ 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72dccc4d start_wqthread + 13
[13:11:17]: ▸ ), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE800001A)., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE800001A).})
```

If I don't have my iPhone connected then this doesn't happen. Maybe the underlying Xcode build commands are trying to use my physical device?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has this been resolved?

Comment: I solved this issue by not having my device plugged in :D It seems like it was trying to use my device for something.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when a device is either connected to the machine running *snapshot*, or paired using Xcode 10's new wireless pairing feature.

Try unplugging your device. If you don't have any devices plugged in, try:

- In Xcode, select Window - Devices & Simulators.
- If you see any devices connected on the left, right-click them and select Unpair.